# Mocking Datacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates(leads) for Integration test

Tags: apex, mock, stubapi

Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction here.

I have this static method as follows...

```
public static void createDupeMap(Lead[] leads) {
    
    CheckExistingRecords cer = new CheckExistingRecords();
    List<Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult> results = cer.findDuplicates(leads);

    //parse results
    if(results!=null && results.size() > 0) {
        for (Integer i=0;i<results.size();i++) {
            for (Datacloud.DuplicateResult dr : results[i].getDuplicateResults()) {
               //do stuff with results
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CheckExistingRecords is a simple class that wraps the Datacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates() method call.

I want to mock/stub the findDuplicates() method so that I have a bunch of expected results I can check for once this createDupeMap method has done it's stuff.

I also then want this mocked method to be pulled in when I do an integration test (so I'm not creating and passing in mocked objects etc).

So I can implement System.StubProvider to mock the CheckExistingRecords class.  The bit I'm stuck on is how to instruct my unit test to employ this mocked class, when in my integration test I'm calling a method much further up the chain.

It sounds reasonable to me but I'm going round in circles a bit here.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to give the answer here in terms of the fflib pattern and ApexMocks (which exploits the StubAPI). The key is to create a service layer that can return a factory-generated service implementation. The factory can return either a mocked service or the real (concrete) service. The code-under-test does not need to know which is present at any given time of execution.

**Application.cls**

```
public static final fflib_Application.ServiceFactory Service = 
        new fflib_Application.ServiceFactory( 
            new Map<Type, Type> {
                    IAccountsService.class              => AccountsServiceImpl.class, 
                     ...
                    ICheckExistingRecordsService.class  => CheckExistingRecordsServiceImpl.class
            });
```

**Service Interface**

```
public interface ICheckExistingRecordsService{   
    List<Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult> findDuplicates(List<Lead> leads);
}
```

**Service redirector/factory**

```
public inherited sharing class CheckExistingRecordsService{
    
    public static List<Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult> findDuplicates(List<Lead> leads) {
        service().findDuplicates(leads);
    }
        
    private static ICheckExistingRecordsService service() {     // factory  
        return (ICheckExistingRecordsService) Application.Service.newInstance(ICheckExistingRecordsService.class);
    }
}
```

**Concrete implementation**

```
public class CheckExistingRecordsServiceImpl implements ICheckExistingRecordsService{
    
    public virtual void findDuplicates(List<Lead> leads) {
        // do the work here
    }
```

**You'll need to change the way you invoke the service in your code to:**

```
List<Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult> results = CheckExistingRecordsService.findDuplicates(leads);
```

**For tests that need to mock this service**

```
// Given some mockDataCloudDuplicates
List<Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult> mockDups = new List<Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult>{
     new Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult ( ... init sobject ),
     new Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult (..),
     ... };

// Given mock service that returns mock dups
CheckExistingRecordsServiceImpl mockCheckExistingRecordsService = (CheckExistingRecordsServiceImpl ) mocks.mock(CheckExistingRecordsServiceImpl .class);
mocks.startStubbing();
mocks.when(mockCheckExistingRecordsService.findDuplicates(
            (Lead[])fflib_Match.anyObject()  // Leads
            .thenReturn(mockDups);
mocks.stopStubbing
//  Given mock Service Injected
Application.Service.setMock(ICheckExistingRecordsService.class,mockCheckExistingRecordsService );
 
// when code-under-test invoked
... whatever

// then verify results
```

So; basically, every request to the `CheckExistingRecordsService.findDuplicates` will use the concrete `CheckExistingRecordsServiceImpl` class unless a mock service is injected in the testmethod:

```
CheckExistingRecordsServiceImpl mockCheckExistingRecordsService = (CheckExistingRecordsServiceImpl ) mocks.mock(CheckExistingRecordsServiceImpl .class);
```

The injection happens through the magic of the Application class which serves as the factory for constructing an object of either the concrete or mocked service. The call to the factory is done in the service class on this line:

```
private static ICheckExistingRecordsService service() {     // factory  
        return (ICheckExistingRecordsService) Application.Service.newInstance(ICheckExistingRecordsService.class);
    }
```

Here's a [link to the fflib_Application.cls](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/blob/master/sfdx-source/apex-common/main/classes/fflib_Application.cls?ts=4) that does this work

OK, a bit long-winded but I can't overemphasize the value of the Enterprise Patterns (aka fflib) to organizing your code to facilitate separation of concerns and mocked implementations of:

- Selectors (so you can return mocked sobjects for any query and avoid DML'ing test data)
- Services (as shown in the answer to your question)
- Domains (especially useful in unit testing trigger handlers; mockable when you have domain methods other than trigger handlers)
- Units of Work (so you can unit test code that does DML without actually doing the DML)

**References**

- [Salesforce Lightning Platform Enterprise Architecture](https://www.packtpub.com/product/salesforce-lightning-platform-enterprise-architecture-third-edition/9781789956719) 3rd edition by Andrew Fawcett
- [Enterprise Patterns](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns) (GitHub; includes introductory doc and further references)

**Notes**

- ApexMocks isn't the only mocking framework around - just happens to be the one I'm most familiar with.

Comment: Hey @cropredy that's some comprehensive answer - thank you.  I'll get onto this tomorrow and get my head around it.  Yes it does seem like quite a lot of work but perhaps I'll find myself rewriting a lot of my unit tests on the back of this.

Comment: chapter 12 of the book (unit testing) was revelatory for me when I first read it (and suggests some alternate, non-fflib mocking patterns). I had read lots of blog posts by Fawcett over the years but the book tied it all together into a coherent piece that was aligned with the latest fflib code on github. Apexmocks is based on Mockito, the mocking framework for Java. John Daniels has some DF sessions that take this a step further into 2GP.  You can use apexmocks w/o fflib patterns but you're going to need a factory and a way to tell the factory to provide a mocked object

Comment: I assume I need to pull fflib into my package to use this pattern?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to construct a new DataCloud.FindDuplicatesResult() as per your answer above?  new Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult ( ... init sobject )

Comment: Use Json.deserialize technique.  Or use the nice wrapper for this in the GitHub SobjectFabricator by Matt Addy

Comment: Get: System.JSONException: No suitable constructor found for type [line:1, column:2] with the serialise/deserialisation technique.  Will check out the wrapper.

Comment: You may need to create a proxy object for this.  I had to do the same for AggregateResult which also can’t be constructed.